# Finding the minimum for a specific time period; And if this minimum is NA, use date just before

Tags: r, date, minimum

I have a dataframe containing stock prices (Adj.Price) of different companies (PERMNO) for two years (2000 and 2001). It also contains the date and the number of the trading day (which basically just counts through the dates):

```
  PERMNO date         Adj.Price day    
    <int> <date>       <dbl> <drtn> 
 1  10001 2000-03-13   5.21  1 days
 2  10001 2000-03-14   5.25  2 days
 3  10001 2000-03-15   5.17  3 days
 4  10001 2000-03-16   5.17  4 days
 5  10001 2000-03-17   5.5   5 days
 6  10001 2000-03-20   5.17  8 days
 7  10001 2000-03-21   5.38  9 days
 8  10001 2000-03-22   5.38 10 days
 9  10001 2000-03-23   5.25 11 days
10  10001 2000-03-24   5.33 12 days
# ... with 3,690,264 more rows
```

I want to calculate the return from the prices of the first day (or date = 2000-03-13) to the day with the lowest stock price in the year 2000 for each PERMNO.
With

```
Crisis_Return <- stock_prices %>% group_by(PERMNO) %>% summarize(stock_return = min(Adj.Price)/Adj.Price[day==1]-1)
```

I can generate a new dataframe that gives me the return between the first day and the overall minimum price. But that also includes prices from 2001. For the lowest price I only want prices from 2000 (i.e. date =< 2000-12-29 or day =< 292). How can I limit the "minmum search" to this time period?

Also, sometimes the last stock price of a PERMNO is given with NA (because the company delisted or went bankrupt). In this case the formula I use would identfy the NA as the minmum and as a result give me a NA as the return. Instead of that, I want to calculate the return till the last day where the company has a valid stock price (ie the row before the NA). Is there a way to do that?

Additionally, when that all works, I would also like to calculate the return between the same minimum stock price as above and the stock price of the day exactly 6 months after (so 6*28=168 days after or 6*20=120 rows below, as the weekends are not included). How can I refer to this vague date?

Comment: instead of `min` use `min(...,na.rm = T)`

Comment: also, use `filter(date =< 2000-12-29)` for prices from 2000 only

Comment: Thank you for your response. The filter function helped a lot, I didnt know about that one. Your solution o the NA unfortunately did not help, because it then just picks the next minimum. I want to pick the last stpck price before the NA field (because that's when the company went bankrupt)

Comment: sure, you are welcome. For you NA problem, instead of `return = min(Adj.Price)...`, use `return = ifelse(is.na(min(Adj.Price)),Adj.Price[which(min[Adj.Price]) - 1],min(Adj.Price))...`

Comment: Hello Vitali, sorry for the late reply.
Thank your for your help. I tried doing your suggestion like this :
```summarise(Stock_Return = (ifelse(is.na(min(Adj.Price)), Adj.Price[which(min[Adj.Price])-1], min(Adj.Price))) / Adj.Price[day==1] - 1)```

Unfortunatly it only gives me out an Error: ```Error in min[Adj.Price] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable.``` Seems to be a problem with usuing min() as a variable, could that be? Do you have an idea how to solve this?